# How is 'let' implemented?

Tags: ios, swift, structure, constants

I pulled this example straight from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) Apple page

```
struct FixedLengthRange {
    var firstValue: Int
    let length: Int
}
```

and if you assign an instance of this structure to a constant,

```
let rangeOfFourItems = FixedLengthRange(firstValue: 0, length: 4)
```

it says we can't change its property values even if it is declared as 'var'

This makes me wonder how `let` is implemented? I hope any assignments to it can be detected at compile time and show compile error. But in the above case, why does it apply to every property of the structure, regardless of how it is defined?

I tried to search for this, finding it very difficult to search with keyword 'let' as it is quite common term.

Can anyone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because a struct is a *value type*. This means it cannot be mutated in place.

Thus, if we have a variable `rangeOfFourItems` that is a FixedLengthRange struct instance, and we want to set `rangeOfFourItems.firstValue`, we are actually ripping the struct instance right out of the `rangeOfFourItems` storage and *replacing* it with *another* struct instance with a different `firstValue`.

To see that this is true, declare `rangeOfFourItems` with `var` and attach a setter observer to it, and then change `rangeOfFourItems.firstValue`:

```
struct FixedLengthRange {
    var firstValue: Int
    let length: Int
}
var rangeOfFourItems = FixedLengthRange(firstValue:1, length:4) {
    didSet {
        print("Hey, you set me!")
    }
}
rangeOfFourItems.firstValue = 2 // Hey, you set me!
```

This shows that merely setting the property of this struct instance actually sets the struct variable itself.

But in *your* code, we cannot do that, because `rangeOfFourItems` prevents this implicit assignment - it is declared with `let`, meaning it must remain a constant. Thus, setting `rangeOfFourItems.firstValue` is prevented at compiler level.

(If FixedLengthRange were a *class* instead of a struct, it would be a *reference type*, and would be mutable in place, and setting `rangeOfFourItems.firstValue` would be legal even if `rangeOfFourItems` was declared with `let`.)

Comment: Thanks. In your "..actually sets the struct variable itself.", Is it also copies all other properties when replacing with new struct instance, since we are merely changing one of its var property?

Comment: That's a deep-voodoo implementation detail that I'd rather not think about. :)

Comment: let i: Int = 0 represents value 0 with type Int. var i = 0 represents variable, which value can be changed.