# Swift protocol settable property through a read-only property

Tags: swift, protocols

Can someone please tell me why Swift has to call the setter of a property when it's only being used to access an object (a protocol) in order to set one of its properties? This first example shows the error I get if I don't declare the indirect object as settable:

```
protocol AProtocol {
    var name: String { get set }
}

class AnImplementation: AProtocol {
    var name = ""
}

class AParent {
    var test = AnImplementation()
}

class AChild {
    var parent: AParent!

    var test: AProtocol {
        get { return parent.test }
        // Note: Not settable
    }
}

var parent = AParent()
var child = AChild()
child.parent = parent

child.test.name = "Hello world!"  // Error: Cannot assign to property : 'test' is a get-only property
print(child.test.name)
```

If I give it a setter, it compiles and works but it calls the setter:

```
protocol AProtocol {
    var name: String { get set }
}

class AnImplementation: AProtocol {
    var name = ""
}

class AParent {
    var test = AnImplementation()
}

class AChild {
    var parent: AParent!

    var test: AProtocol {
        get { return parent.test }
        set(newTest) { print("Shouldn't be here!") }
    }
}

var parent = AParent()
var child = AChild()
child.parent = parent

child.test.name = "Hello world!"
print(child.test.name)
```

Output is:

```
Shouldn't be here!
Hello world!
```

I'm not sure what I'm not understanding here. I assume I can just give it an empty setter, but I'd like to understand the reason for it.

Any information is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your protocol declaration to this:

```
protocol AProtocol:class {
    var name: String { get set }
}
```

Otherwise, it is taken by default as a *value type*. Changing a value type's property replaces the value type instance (as shown by the setter observer). And you can't do that if the reference is a `let` reference.

Comment: On value type setters, see for example my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33901138/341994

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by the fact that the compiler doesn't know whether `AChild.test` is a class or a value type. With classes there is no problem but with value types assigning to `name` would also create an assignment to `test` (value-copy behavior). Marking `APProtocol` as `class` protocol will fix the problem.

To expand, when the compiler is not sure whether `test` is a value or a class type, it will use the following rewrite of `child.test.name = "Hello world!"`:

```
var tmp = child.test
tmp.test = "Hello world!"
child.test = tmp
```

because that will work for both class and value types.