# Conceptual questions about Struct's immutability and property changes from within the struct and from the instance

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct Test {
    var a: Int
    
    func changeA() {
        a = 10
    }
}

var testInstance = Test(a: 10)
testInstance.a = 1
```

1. I understand, Structs are immutable, nonetheless the Swift compiler allows me to change Property "a" to 1, after it was already initialized to 10, were Structs immutable? why this is allowed?
2. If the Swift compiler allows to change property "a" from the instance, why it doesn't allow to have the method "changeA" to modify "a" from within the Struct without adding the "mutating" modifier? It seems it is allowed to modify the property from the instance, but not from a method within the Struct, why?
3. These are more conceptual questions, I fully understand that I can add "mutating" in front of the method and it will compile, but why I have to do that, if by default I am allowed to modify the property from outside the method after initialization, why the extra level of rigor with "mutating" to modify a property, that it is already declared as "var"?

I am very much interested in the theory and concepts behind Struct's immutability.

Comment: You might enjoy reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901138/341994

Comment: As for the `mutating` keyword, why Swift has that is sort of a matter of opinion. That's just how the language is. You don't really get to question it.

Comment: Another good read is [Structures and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) from The Swift Programming Language book

Answer (score 1):

You have variable and constant variables. Variable is marked with `var`, constant variables is market with `let`.
So you are not able to modify properties of constant `let`s and not able to call mutating methods. So to mark method that are not allowed for constants, they are notated with `mutating`

Answer (score 1):

Structures are value type. When you create an instance from structure , it creates copy .

in function `createA` without mutating , it works like `self.a = 10` . If swift allow that , when you call this function from any instance , it will effect the main structure properties , gonna run like reference type.Lıke

```
struct Test {
    var a: Int = 3

    func changeA() {
        a = 10
    }
}

 var testInstance = Test()
 testInstance.changeA()
 //testInstance.a = 10
 
 var testInstance1 = Test()
 //testInstance1.a =  10
 var testInstanc2 = Test()
```

If mutating doesnt exist. changeA() works like class and `testInstance1.a` would not be 3 anymore .

When you add `'mutating'` to your function . It not use `self` it actually create a new instance from self . Function actually work like

```
mutating func changeA() {
    Test().a = 10
}
```

and when the method ends , `its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends.` [link here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html)

Thats why we have to use mutating.